# How can I create an orthographic render similar to the Portal 2 promotional videos?

Tags: rendering, workflow, camera

Some of the [*Portal*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal_%28video_game%29) and [*Portal 2*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal_2) promotional videos have a 2D/3Dish world in an orthographic/isometric view.

I know how to set the camera to orthographic in Blender, but how would I go about creating the 2D-style characters? Also, which render engine should I use? Any tips on how to create something similar would be appreciated.

[Reference #1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0qcED35LL8I)
[Reference #2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w5I3VnCHWsU)

Comment: I'm guessing you want Toon or Cel shading? Or would [Freestyle](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Freestyle) work for you?

Comment: This question is open ended, and is several questions rolled into one. The best way to use this site is to focus on one thing. For example you could show a render and node setup of how you tried to approach this yourself, then people here can offer insight by suggestion their interpretations. As it stands no-one knows what you have tried already, or what level you are at currently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not clear on what aspects your question is focussed. For this orthographic render I used BI since freestyle isn't available when using cycles. The caracters were made from a plane with a few extrusions and a circle.

[image]

Enable freestyle in the render tab :

[image]

To control which objects get outline,  create a group (here desk and sitting guy) after that go to the *Render Layers Tab* select the group in the highlighted box (red).

[image]

If you want to use cycles you might be interested in [blender-cycles-toon-material-node-setup](http://nixart.wordpress.com/2012/05/19/blender-cycles-toon-material-node-setup/)

Comment: OT: nice Theme! Is this a modified Elsyiun? Would you mind to share that?

Comment: @Germar It's the energy theme you can download here: http://studiollb.wordpress.com/download/

Comment: Cool theme. Thanks for the link. And, of course, the answer to the question. It looks pretty close to what I'm trying to achieve.